# WebView in compose Loading each time is an issue

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have applied accompanist webview in compose. Now if i open the composable again the url is loading each time i click which i dont want. What can i do here

[image: This is the video]

Answer (score 1):

Replace the following first line that you probably use currently

```
val webViewState = rememberWebViewState("https://example.com")

WebView(
    state = webViewState
)
```

with the snippet below:

```
val webViewState = rememberSaveableWebViewState()
val navigator = rememberWebViewNavigator()

LaunchedEffect(navigator) {
    val bundle = webViewState.viewState
    if (bundle == null) {
        // This is the first time load, so load the home page.
        // Whenever you open this Composable again, the current route is not reloaded
        navigator.loadUrl("https://example.com")
    }
}
```

You need at least Accompanist version `0.31.1-alpha` to do this. Also see the [related GitHub issue](https://github.com/google/accompanist/pull/1557).

Comment: ok so I got the issue, I have wrapped my WebView inside a lazyColumn that caused the issue now it is fixed. Thanks for immediate support.